# Need to add LF to thousands of MySQL MEDIUMTEXT fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to add a `\n` or `LF` or `ASCII(x'0A')` or however you want to encode it to the end of several thousand MySQL MEDIUMTEXT fields. I tried

```
update wp_posts set post_content = concat(post_content,ASCII(x'0A'));
```

but nothing is modified in the field as far as I can see. I suspect this is a limitation of MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT fields, but it would be nice if MySQL would throw an error instead of saying it did something and doing nothing.

If I can't do it with update/concat, what other options do I have? Does someone have a chunk of php code I can use to do it in a loop?

Thanks for any input! I'm trying to get my wordpress site to validate with W3C, and I need the newlines so wordpress does not add a `<p>` tag inappropriately. Strange, I know.

Comment: How do you know it hasn't worked? When rendered in a web browser a \n character won't display as a new line unless you view the html source.

Comment: The MySQL GUI Workbench will let you look at the binary content of any database column. That should let you determine if anything changed as @Mark Baker indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update wp_posts set post_content = concat(post_content,'\n');
```

I tested with a mediumtext field here and worked..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where my brain was. I was using HeidiSQL as the interface to MySQL, and wasn't seeing the change in the database. But it did change, which I saw once I refreshed the table data. Sorry for the false question!